# vs code c# omnisharp , how can I debug external library

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I am trying to step through my ASP net core library code in visual studio code and don't know how to basically disable "just my code" and attach pdbs.

The default stack inspecting omnisharp  behavior during a breakpoint hit is:

```
MyNamespace.MyCLass.function()    
[External Code] (\Unknown Source:0)
```

How can I debug external library code?

Answer (score 2):

It seams that I needed to edit vs code's  `launch.json` workspace file according to :

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
the section with 
`"justMyCode":false` , `"requireExactSource": false` and `"symbolPath": [ "/Volumes/symbols" ]`

Now the problem is the symbols. Can't seam to find .net core symbols for public releases of asp net mvc.
I will have to manually compile https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc ,and all the other middleware I am interested in.